# how to include sap hana vora external jar in build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, vora

I am trying to build a spark application to access hana vora content.

my scala code is

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object Vora_Test{
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
 val sconf = new SparkConf().setAppName("VoraTestApp")
 val sc = new SparkContext(sconf)
 val sqlc = new SapSQLContext(sc)
 val queryResult = sqlc.sql("SELECT * from DATA")
 queryResult.collect().foreach(println)

 }
}
```

I want to include the third party jar "spark-sap-datasources-1.2.33-assembly.jar" in my build.  I tried sbt package, sbt assembly

I used the following build.sbt

```
name := "VoraApp"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"



libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2",

"com.sap.spark" % "extensiondist" % "1.2.37" from "file:///local/file/loc/lib/spark-sap-datasources-1.2.33-assembly.jar")
```

Nothing worked.  I am getting the below error

Compiling 1 Scala source to local/file/loc/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] bad symbolic reference. A signature in ExtendableSQLContext.class refers to type SQLContext
[error] in package org.apache.spark.sql which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling ExtendableSQLContext.class.

How to overcome this error.  I am new to scala, sbt, spark and vora.

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing this dependency:

`"org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "1.5.1"`

Answer (score 0):

Is that the actual path to the file? It looks unusual to me...

> file:///local/file/loc/lib/spark-sap-datasources-1.2.33-assembly.jar

Comment: I have to change the build.sbt to include it in fat jar